# NEED HELP **triggers with join**

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

two tables

**users**

- user_id , username , password , email

**posts**

- user_id , post_id , post

i want to join these two tables by user_id and create new table

**posts_join**

- user_id , username , post

but now i dont know how to make trigger of this problem i want to update post_join when there is an insertion in posts table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `posts_join` table is duplicating the function of the foreign key in the `posts` table.

Remove the `posts_join` table from your database and replace it with a view:

```
create view posts_join
as
select  u.user_id
,       username
,       post
from    posts p 
join    users u
on      u.user_id = p.user_id
```

Comment: @Barmar: Right, updated

Comment: i want to use select * from recent_data (table) in php page to display 
 
 CREATE TABLE recent_data AS    
  SELECT
  user_id,username,post
  FROM post_join;
is this correct ..?

Comment: A web page should not normally create tables at all?  Instead use a view to retrieve information to display.

Comment: i am explaining the reason for  creating the recent_data table using view sir , 

CREATE TABLE recent_data AS SELECT user_id,username,post FROM post_join;

- i created view 
- then i create table using the view
- after that i am thinking to retrieve information from database to display on my webpage using select * from recent_data
am i doing it in a perfect track or not ..!

Comment: i did exactly same thing but it wont updating recent_data table
after insertion in post table

Comment: @johnscoop A view automatically runs the query whenever you use it, it's like a macro. If you create a real table, you need to create a trigger to update it whenver one of the other tables changes.

Comment: thanks for this wonderful help ..!